# How to zip a folder recursively, but only selective files, in Windows?

Tags: windows, zip

For example, I have this directory structure:

```
[C:\]
+ [Documents]
  + [Work] 
    + [Presentation]
      - Presentation A.pptx
      - Presentation B.pptx
      - Presentation C.pptx
      - Presentation D.pptx
    + [Account]
      - General Ledger.xlsx
      - Additional Report.xlsx
  + [Home]
    + [Kid's School]
      - School Enrollment List.docx
      - Weekly Newsletter 1.pdf
      - Weekly Newsletter 2.pdf
      - Weekly Newsletter 3.pdf
    + [Email Attachment]
      - Stores Weekly Discount.pdf
      - Teddy's Birthday Photo.jpg
```

Supposed that I want to zip only:

- Presentation B.pptx
- Additional Report.xlsx
- Weekly Newsletter 3.pdf
- Whole folder of [Email Attachment]

But I want to preserve the folder structure, so that the zip file will contain file structure like this:

```
Documents\Work\Presentation\Presentation B.pptx
Documents\Work\Account\Additional Report.xlsx
Documents\Home\Kid's School\Weekly Newsletter 3.pdf
Documents\Home\Email Attachment\Stores Weekly Discount.pdf
Documents\Home\Email Attachment\Teddy's Birthday Photo.jpg
```

How to do that? All I did until now is by zipping the whole folder of Documents, and then selectively erase it within the zip file. But this is very time consuming, because the real case is the folders level are deep, with hundreds of files, and the files' size are big.

Do you know any native way, or any external program that allows me to do this? I think something like there's an option at Windows Explorer to zip a folder, but then the zip program presented a folder tree with checkbox in front of every files and folders to mark which files and folders to be included in the resulting zip files, if there any program like that exists. Thanks.

Comment: A terminal program that lets you add only files in a specific list would work. I know `tar` can do that, I'm sure a terminal zip program for windows exists, maybe newer than the old pkzip ones? Try a web search for windows terminal zip?

Comment: Alright I'll looking up for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) should be able to use a list of files to zip, and it can use either it's own `.7z` format or regular `.zip` format.

[This page](http://comptb.cects.com/automate-compression-tasks-cli/) describes how it should work, uses the `@file` list of files feature:

> ### Using List files
>
> List files are files that contain a list of one or more files and/or
>   directories separated by new line symbols. Both the 7-Zip and IZArc
>   command line utilities can use list files for processing files and
>   directories. 7-Zip uses UTF-8 encoding for list files by default, but
>   the encoding can be changed at the command line using the “-scs”
>   switch if necessary (see the command line version section in 7-zip.chm
>   for further information).
>
> The command line syntax for compressing files and/or directories with
>   a list file:
>
> For 7-Zip:
>
> ```
> 7za a -tzip "C:\Your Folder\yourarchive.zip @"C:\Your Folder\yourlistfile.txt"
> ```
>
> - 7za – the 7-Zip command-line executable.
> - a – add files to the archive command.
> - -tzip – set archive type to a zip file (optional unless using another compression format).

---

Using [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) and then use linux tools like `tar` should work too, but that's definitely overkill and unnecessary for just a zip program. There are a few [`tar` for windows](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=tar%20for%20windows) programs, but I'd stick with 7zip.

Another idea might be a separate folder that only has **links** to the files you want, keeping the original folder structure. It would create a "mirror" of the original files that are always identical to their linked originals.  Then just backup all the files in that separate folder, as long as it zips the actual link target files & not just the links.

Comment: Wait. What do you mean by links?

Comment: File links / symbolic links, symlinks, like "soft" or "hard" links. A "file-like" thing that points to another real file somewhere else. This is a decent page that has some how-to's, not sure what version of Windows you're on but these *should* work for anything current: [Using Symlinks in Windows Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/) . Wikipedia has something to say about [NTFS Symbolic Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) too

Comment: Oh I see. I get what you mean. So the file will be keep updated as the original file is updated. There's still a problem though. The file needed to be compressed most likely will be different each time. Maybe today I want to compress file `document\A`, `data\finance\B`, and `photo\C`. Next time I might needed to compress file `music\pop\X`, `presentation\monday\Y`, and `project\java\Z`. This makes building empty folder structures and making soft links impractical, and which is why I really need the selective zip program. But thank you for elaborating. :)

Comment: @ChenLiYong I think I've got a solution using 7-zip that should work with a text list of files to zip. I'll edit the answer to add it :-)